# Python OpenGL glRotatef - looking for the correct multiplier

Tags: python, opengl, rotation, pyopengl

I am using gluLookAt with a camera whose coordinates are xCam, yCam and zCam. The coordinates of the object the camera is looking at are xPos, yPos, and zPos. There are variables named mouseturnX and mouseturnY, which measure the deviation of the mouse from the middle of the screen in the x-axis and the y-axis. The variable camdist describes the distance between camera and the object it looks at.

The code of the cameraposition is this:

```
xCam = sin(mouseturnX)*camdist+xPos
yCam = mouseturnY+yPos
zCam = cos(mouseturnX)*camdist+zPos
```

I now made a polygon object, which I rotate with:

```
glRotatef(mouseturnX,0,1,0)
```

Usually it should only show me the backside of the object, it does not matter which position the camera has. But now it does not turn correctly. I tried it with other rotation-axises, there it works fine, but with the y-axis it just does not want to work. I tried changing the camdist from positive to negative, the mouseturnX in the glRotatef function from positive to negative and back to positive again. It just does not work. I used **glPushMatrix** before the rotation command and **glPopMatrix** after it. One line before the rotation command I used the translate function to set a fixpoint for the polygon.

Edit: The polygon actually spins, but not in the right amount. It seems like I have to multiply the rotation of the polygon with something.

Comment: `glRotatef` does not set a rotation, but defines a rotation matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the rotation matrix. The order matters. Matrix multiplications are not [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). What matrix operations are you doing before and after `glRotatef`?

Comment: I used glPushMatrix() before glRotatef and glPopMatrix() after glRotatef. And if it matters, one line before glRotatef I used the translate function for the polygon modelling.

Comment: You must add this information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the multiplicator by trying. It is 56.5. It is not perfect, but it works.